# SQL query to get the details of students who have continuously increasing marks in each semester from the Marks table

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I am having a table marks, I need to print the details of names having continuously increasing marks.
Table : Marks

```
Name    Sem Marks
A       1   80
A       2   90
A       3   95
B       1   80
B       2   70
B       3   90
C       1   80
C       2   85
C       3   90
```

Output:

```
Name    Sem Marks
A       1   80
A       2   90
A       3   95
C       1   80
C       2   85
C       3   90
```

Can any one give me the MySQL query to print the output

Tried using analytical functions(lead, lag) but getting name with B also.

Current query

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Name, Sem, Marks, LAG(Marks,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sem) AS Prev_Marks FROM Marks ) SELECT Name, Sem, Marks FROM cte WHERE Marks > Prev_Marks OR Prev_Marks IS NULL ORDER BY Name, Sem;
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect ___some effort from you___ to solve your own problem before asking a question. So show us your best effort. 
___SO is not a free coding service___, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: Its always best to show us an attempt, it shows you are not just asking us to do your work for you, it also shows us a bit about your current ability

Comment: Tried below query
but getting Name with B. struck at this place how to avoid student B values:

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Name, Sem, Marks,
         LAG(Marks,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sem) AS Prev_Marks
  FROM Marks
)
SELECT Name, Sem, Marks
FROM cte
WHERE Marks > Prev_Marks OR Prev_Marks IS NULL
ORDER BY Name, Sem;

Output I am getting is

Name Sem Marks
A 1 80
A 2 90
A 3 95
B 1 80
B 3 90
C 1 80
C 2 85
C 3 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight modification to your existing query you could use a correlation with *not exists*:

```
with d as (
  select Name,
  case 
    when Lag(Marks,1) over (partition by Name order by Sem) > Marks then 1
  end Decreasing
 from Marks
)
select Name, Sem, Marks 
from Marks m
where not exists (
  select * from d 
  where d.name = m.name and d.Decreasing = 1
)
order by name, sem;
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8AeHu3gG)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `rank()` to rank Marks then check if the rank and Sem are equal in every level.

```
WITH cte AS ( 
  SELECT Name, Sem, Marks,
  rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Marks) AS rank_mark 
  FROM Marks 
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, if(Sem = rank_mark, 1, 0) as 'isUp'
  FROM cte
)
select t.*
from Marks t
left join (
  select Name
  from cte2 
  where isUp = 0
  group by Name
) as s on s.Name = t.Name 
WHERE s.Name is null;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4rSURmzBYTSsbTqNM4LJqk/1)

Comment: Thanks SelVazi. Able to get the output 
Thanks for your valuable time to give your solution

Comment: @RKJohnny the common way to say "thank you" on SO is to accept the answer and upvote ;)